# Is there a current (11/2017) way to parse the Ethereum blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, parser

I understand there exist many (defunct/unsupported to date) blockchain explorer project and rate-limited web APIs exist for culling Ethereum data from the .ldb blockchain files. But what about bulk processing of the .ldb files on a local node?  Is there a (preferably python based) parser scheme?

Is there a recommended to date? For being a public ledger, it is quit difficult to actually access any of the data...

Comment: Are you trying to parse things that happened in the past, or stream live data?

Answer (score 1):

You can try QuickBlocks. It's C++, not Python, but it fully supported and actively developed: https://github.com/Great-Hill-Corporation/quickBlocks

Answer (score -1):

To stream blockchain data for real-time analysis, make sure you have both geth and mongo running and start the process with:
  python3 stream.py

https://github.com/alex-miller-0/Ethereum_Blockchain_Parser